# Append single quote (') to a Special Character String using Java

Tags: java, string, replace, special-characters, single-quotes

I want to append the single quote for the String which consists of only the special characters. This is what I want to achieve :-

```
String sp = ''{+#)''&$;
```

Result should be :-

```
'''' {+#)''''&$
```

That means for every single quote we need to append 1 single quote that too at that particular index.

Below is my code which I have tried :-

```
public static String appendSingleQuote(String randomStr) {
        if (randomStr.contains("'")) {
            long count = randomStr.chars().filter(ch -> ch == '\'').count();
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
                int index = randomStr.indexOf("'");
                randomStr = addChar(randomStr, '\'', index);
            }
            System.out.println(randomStr);
        }
        return randomStr;
    }

    private static String addChar(String randomStr, char ch, int index) {
        return randomStr.substring(0, index) + ch + randomStr.substring(index);
    }
```

But this is giving result like this :-

```
'''''' {+#)''&$
```

Any suggestions on this? The String can contain even and odd number of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YCF_L's solution should solve your problem. But if you still want to use your method you can try this one below:

```
public String appendSingleQuote(String randomStr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0 ; index < randomStr.length() ; index++) {
        sb.append(randomStr.charAt(index) == '\'' ? "''" : randomStr.charAt(index));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It simply iterates through your string and changes every single quote (') with ('')

Answer (score 4):

All you need is just `replace` :

```
String str = "''{+#)''&$";
str = str.replace("'", "''");
```

Outputs

```
''''{+#)''''&$
```

Comment: No. Only append the single quote. No need to use double quotes.

Comment: What if it contains odd number of single quotes?

Comment: @avidCoder you have to specify this in your question, ok, I will gives you another way, but you have to share the output for the odd quotes

Comment: @avidCoder for odd quotes `'''{+#)''&$` the output is `''''''{+#)''''&$`

Comment: Oh.. that's cool. I didn't know the functionality of replace properly.. thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to use [**String** `.replaceAll()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String sp =" ''{+#)''&$";
sp.replaceAll("\'", "''")
```

This is a [live working **Demo**](https://repl.it/@chsdk/Replace-a-single-quote-with-two-single-quotes-in-a-string).

**Note:**

Using a `for` loop for this is an overkill when `.replace()` or `.replaceAll()` are enough, there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: why replaceAll? There is no regex involved

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, my bad I was using the regex in the beginning, and then edited it before posting it.